# Show tab bar and listIn Actionbar at same time. (Android Honeycomb)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-3.0-honeycomb, android-actionbar

There is a situation in which I want to use Tab bar as well as List navigation, Both at same time in Action bar.

Documentation says 'we can put Actionbar in to list navigation mode or tabs navigation mode'.

Is there any way to use both at same time. Any pointers, help. Thank you in Advance.

Answer (score 5):

Sorry, you can only have one or the other.

That being said, you can use `android:actionLayout` to convert an options menu item into a custom inflated layout in the action bar. You might be able to use the "tabs navigation mode" while putting your own `Spinner` to the right of the tabs this way. Personally, I would find this confusing as a user, but perhaps it will work for your use case.

Comment: Can you give some link/example for android:actionLayout?

Comment: @Sagar: Here is a sample project where I use this: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Menus/ActionBar Here is a nearly identical sample project, but one that will work both on Honeycomb and on older versions of Android: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Menus/ActionBarBC

Comment: Android is missing sub navigation pretty badly. :( We have a mixture of sub navigation patterns due to the lack of support in the framework. Pretty disappointing for the developer and the user.

Answer (score 2):

a very late answer, but this is possible by a simple hack. You just have to replace (programatically) the view that is pointed by `android.R.id.action_bar_title` with a `Spinner`. I wrote a blog about it. Here's the [link](http://www.hasnath.net/blog/actionbar-tab-spinnerlist-navigation-at-the-same-time)